# Python append to list from return tuple

Tags: python

I have a list and a function `f` which returns a 3-tuple.   I would like to capture the first two return values, and with the third, append to lst.  I know I can do the following:

```
a, b, c = f()
lst.append(c)
```

but I would like a way not to have the extraneous variable "c".  I know I can also do:

```
lst.append(f()[2])
```

but I do not want to throw away the other two return values.
Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I appreciate the answers provided, but the question, put more clearly, is to find a neat one-liner.

Comment: `c` doesn't seem to be extraneous since you are using it.

Comment: Can I ask where the concern comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible with a "one liner" (without using semi-colon to fit two statements on a single line) *unless* you change your function definition.

Specifically, define `f()` in the following way:

```
def f(list_to_append_to):
    a = ...
    b = ...
    c = ...
    list_to_append_to.append(c)
    return a, b
```

Then:

```
a, b = f(mylist)
```

Comment: Cool side effect.

Answer (score 4):

Assign the return value to a local variable before you append the result.
No, you can't catch two values and append the third in one statement; you only get one "verb" per command.

```
result = f()
lst.append(result[2])
```

Comment: @AGNGazer Don't be so sure. If the OP wants all the values from `f`, but didn't want three different variables, this may be what the OP is looking for.  (I will admit my original reaction was the same as yours, though).  Until the OP clarifies what their issue is with their original approach we can't really make this judgement.

Comment: @AGNGazer, OK, now that the OP has updated stating that they just want a one-liner, your comment is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is not saving yourself with writing one more line of code, but you would just want the function call, the assignment and the appendix in a single statement, you could use a wrapper function:

```
def append_and_assign(mylist, myfunc):
    a, b, c = myfunc()
    mylist.append(c)
    return a,b,c
```

and so you can call:

```
 a,b,c = append_and_assign(lst, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to one-line this, but I wouldn't recommend doing so as it lacks readability:

```
a, b, (lst.append(None) or lst)[-1] = f()
```

Since the append method returns `None`, `or`ing it with the `lst` will return `lst` itself. Then, use `-1` as the index to overwrite the recently appended `None` (you could use any value instead of `None`).